# FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase in node.js but every time I restart the server I am getting following error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your apiKey and databaseURL match the values provided for your app at https://console.firebase.google.com/, or if you're using a service account, make sure it's authorized to access the specified databaseURL and is from the correct project.

Following is my index.js:_

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var admin=mongoose.model('admin');


var firebase = require("firebase");

// Initialize the app with no authentication
firebase.initializeApp({
   serviceAccount: {
    projectId: "...",
    clientEmail: "...",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...",
  },

      databaseURL: "..."
});

console.log("sfsaf")

// The app only has access to public data as defined in the Security Rules
   var db = firebase.database();
   var ref = db.ref("unitalk-b9145");
   var messagesRef = ref.child("messages");
   
   messagesRef.push({
    name:"Rupali",
    post:"Demo test of firebase"
   });
```

Although I have checked the path of service-account and databaseURl..
Please help..

Comment: I get a similar message: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.

Answer (score 1):

You can not log in with the service account using the "firabase" package. You need to use the "firabase-admin" package for this. You can find detailed information here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

UPDATED: 8 Nov 2016

go to : https://console.firebase.google.com

To use the Firebase Admin SDKs, you'll need a Firebase project, a service account to communicate with the Firebase service, and a configuration file with your service account's credentials.

1. Navigate to the Service Accounts tab in your project's settings
   page.
2. Select your Firebase project. If you don't already have one, click
   the Create New Project button. If you already have an existing
   Google project associated with your app, click Import Google Project
   instead.
3. Click the Generate New Private Key button at the bottom of the
   Firebase Admin SDK section of the Service Accounts tab.
4. After you click the button, a JSON file containing your service
   account's credentials will be downloaded. You'll need this to
   initialize the SDK in the next step.

Sample code;

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: @Halil-I have include "firabase-admin" package and update with following code.
** admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "unitalk-b9145",
    clientEmail: "uni2-522@unitalk-b9145.iam.gserdviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE ---"
  }),

    databaseURL: "https://unitalk-b9145.firsebaseio.com/"
});**

Comment: But giving following error-  Cannot read property 'cert' of undefined

Comment: I have done the above 4points mentioned by you above and updated the following code- 
    var firebase = require("firebase");
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");


    var serviceAccount = require("serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/"
});

Comment: but doing this Iam getting error-Cannot find module 'serviceAccountKey.json'...As this is not a node module so how can we require..It is path of downloaded  key in json

Comment: Instead of "service Account Key.json" you need to copy the downloaded file to the project directory and give it the path.

Comment: I have done the same..i.e. downloaded the file put in my routes folder and gave the path..For eg name of file is "abc.json".So,I kept in my routes folder and use following:-var serviceAccount = require("abc.json");

Comment: This produces `FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid.` with credentials in the file that work with using the `firebase` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Another method to solve the issue link](https://itayhauptman.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/firebase-firebase-warning-provided-authentication-credentials-are-invalid-this-usually-indicates-your-firebaseapp-instance-was-not-initialized-correctly/)

for those who still facing this issue, you may try on this method, this is related to the project roles management according to the description inside

Comment: After doing this, you can also disable and re-enable the cloud functions as directed [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/147#issuecomment-360543445)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this recently. I had the problem with Firebase function, after changing project. It went away when i removed the keys from admin.initializeApp()
Apparently firebase functions now know to use the project credentials. So just this;

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using require('firebase') module so u need the following things:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: " [your api key]",
  authDomain: "[projectname].firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://[projectname].firebaseio.com/",
  storageBucket: "[projectname].appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "[message id]",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

If you want to use  require("firebase-admin") then you have to configure
serviceAccountKey.json(downloaded file) file  ...
I am able to connect with firebase successfully.

Comment: var firebase = require('firebase');
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
   credential: FirebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),  
   databaseURL: "https://nodewithfirebase.firebaseio.com/"
});

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    FirebaseAdmin.database().ref('/users').set({
        username: "test",
        email: "test@mail.com"
    });
    res.send("firebase app");
});